# Calculating percentage changes in data frame subsets using a base year

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following dataset with information on the sales figures for two companies over a period of five years. I want to use the first year's figure as a baseline and calculate the percentage change in sales for each subsequent year for each company. I use the following:

```
transform(dataset, SalesD = unlist(aggregate(Sales ~ Company, function(x) ((x - x[1]) / x[1]) * 100, data=Dataset)$Sales))
```

yet I do not get the correct values for the second company (I expect the value at row 6 to be zero, as this is the base year). Here are the results:

```
+----+---------+------+--------+--------+
| ID | Company | Year | Sales  | SalesD |
+----+---------+------+--------+--------+
|  1 | LSL     | 2015 | 100000 |      0 |
|  2 | LSL     | 2016 | 120000 |     20 |
|  3 | LSL     | 2017 | 150000 |     50 |
|  4 | LSL     | 2018 | 100000 |      0 |
|  5 | LSL     | 2019 |  50000 |    -50 |
|  6 | IDA     | 2015 | 150000 |     50 |
|  7 | IDA     | 2016 | 180000 |     80 |
|  8 | IDA     | 2017 | 200000 |    100 |
|  9 | IDA     | 2018 | 180000 |     80 |
| 10 | IDA     | 2019 | 160000 |     60 | 
+----+---------+------+--------+--------+
```

Could you help me point out what is wrong in the code?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by "Company", we get the percentage change by subtracting the "Sales" from the value of "Sales" that corresponds to `min` value of "Year", multiply by 100, `round` and assign (`:=`) to create "SalesD".

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, SalesD := round(100*(Sales- 
         Sales[which.min(Year)])/Sales[which.min(Year)]) , Company]
df1
#     ID Company Year  Sales SalesD
# 1:  1     LSL 2015 100000      0
# 2:  2     LSL 2016 120000     20
# 3:  3     LSL 2017 150000     50
# 4:  4     LSL 2018 100000      0
# 5:  5     LSL 2019  50000    -50
# 6:  6     IDA 2015 150000      0
# 7:  7     IDA 2016 180000     20
# 8:  8     IDA 2017 200000     33
# 9:  9     IDA 2018 180000     20
#10: 10     IDA 2019 160000      7
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it did it! (Though I need to read a bit on the data.table library, I am not very much acquainted with it)

Comment: @orestisf You can check the [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf) and [FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf)